# Trigger Handler Using fflib - Single method multiple context handling

Tags: triggercontext

I have been able to use the trigger contexts separately in a single method in a handler class before but now i am using the fflib and i am probably just over thinking it. How can i get my  method to handle different contexts separately.

This is the method i am using currently on updates. However, for inserts i need it to automatically query for the related account's currency and update the currency on the case to match. I could just duplicate the logic to get it working but i know there is a better way without duplicating this method.

```
public static void setCurrencyToMatchAccount(list<Case> records, Map<Id, SObject> existingRecords){
    set<Id> casesToMatchAcctCurrency = new set<Id>(); 
    for(Case record : (List<Case>) records){
        Case previous = (case)existingRecords.get(record.Id);
        string recordtypename = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosById().get(record.recordtypeid).getname();
        if(previous.AccountId != record.AccountId && recordtypename.contains('Adjustment') || trigger.isInsert){
            casesToMatchAcctCurrency.add(record.id);
        }
    }
    if(casesToMatchAcctCurrency.size() > 0) {

        map<id,case> casesToUpdateMap = new map<id,case>();
        set<Id> caseIdsWithAdjLineItems = new set<Id>();
       for(case case0 : [select id, CurrencyIsoCode, recordtypeid, AccountId, Account.MS_Billing_Currency__c, Adj_Line_Item_Count__c FROM Case where id IN: casesToMatchAcctCurrency]) {
           if(case0.AccountId != null) {
               if(case0.Account.MS_Billing_Currency__c == 'EUR' || case0.Account.MS_Billing_Currency__c == 'CAD') {
                    case0.CurrencyISOCode = case0.Account.MS_Billing_Currency__c;
                } else {
                    case0.CurrencyISOCode = 'USD';
                }

                if(case0.Adj_Line_Item_Count__c > 0) {
                    caseIdsWithAdjLineItems.add(case0.Id);
                }
                casesToUpdateMap.put(case0.id,case0);
            }
        }
        database.update(casesToUpdateMap.values());

        list<Adjustment_Line_Items__c> adjLineItemsToUpdate = new list<Adjustment_Line_Items__c>();
        for(Adjustment_Line_Items__c ali : [select id, CurrencyIsoCode, Case__c from Adjustment_Line_Items__c where Case__c IN: caseIdsWithAdjLineItems]) {
            if(ali.CurrencyIsoCode != casesToUpdateMap.get(ali.Case__c).CurrencyIsoCode) {
                ali.CurrencyIsoCode = casesToUpdateMap.get(ali.Case__c).CurrencyIsoCode;
                adjLineItemsToUpdate.add(ali);
            }
        }
        database.update(adjLineItemsToUpdate);
    }
}
```

Even just a link to an example will probably get me what i need but i have not been able to find a solid one that was easily readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized i still have access to basic trigger context info -

```
    public static void setCurrencyToMatchAccount(list<Case> records, Map<Id, SObject> existingRecords){
    set<Id> casesToMatchAcctCurrency = new set<Id>(); 

    for(Case record : (List<Case>) records){
        Case previous = new Case();
        if(trigger.isUpdate) {
            previous = (case)existingRecords.get(record.Id);
        }
        string recordtypename = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosById().get(record.recordtypeid).getname();
        if((previous.AccountId != record.AccountId || trigger.isInsert) && recordtypename.contains('Adjustment') ){
            casesToMatchAcctCurrency.add(record.id);
        }
    }
    if(casesToMatchAcctCurrency.size() > 0) {

        map<id,case> casesToUpdateMap = new map<id,case>();
        set<Id> caseIdsWithAdjLineItems = new set<Id>();
       for(case case0 : [select id, CurrencyIsoCode, recordtypeid, AccountId, Account.MS_Billing_Currency__c, Adj_Line_Item_Count__c FROM Case where id IN: casesToMatchAcctCurrency]) {
           if(case0.AccountId != null) {
               if(case0.Account.MS_Billing_Currency__c == 'EUR' || case0.Account.MS_Billing_Currency__c == 'CAD') {
                    case0.CurrencyISOCode = case0.Account.MS_Billing_Currency__c;
                } else {
                    case0.CurrencyISOCode = 'USD';
                }

                if(case0.Adj_Line_Item_Count__c > 0) {
                    caseIdsWithAdjLineItems.add(case0.Id);
                }
                casesToUpdateMap.put(case0.id,case0);
            }
        }
        database.update(casesToUpdateMap.values());
        list<Adjustment_Line_Items__c> adjLineItemsToUpdate = new list<Adjustment_Line_Items__c>();
        if(trigger.isUpdate) {
            for(Adjustment_Line_Items__c ali : [select id, CurrencyIsoCode, Case__c from Adjustment_Line_Items__c where Case__c IN: caseIdsWithAdjLineItems]) {
                if(ali.CurrencyIsoCode != casesToUpdateMap.get(ali.Case__c).CurrencyIsoCode) {
                    ali.CurrencyIsoCode = casesToUpdateMap.get(ali.Case__c).CurrencyIsoCode;
                    adjLineItemsToUpdate.add(ali);
                }
            }
        }
        database.update(adjLineItemsToUpdate);
    }
}
```